# Convert string to datetime format in databricks using sql

Tags: sql, datetime, azure-databricks

I am facing error while converting the string to datetime format in databricks  :

```html
select to_date('01Jan1971:00:00:00','DDMONYYYY:HH:MI:SS')
```

```
Error in SQL statement: IllegalArgumentException: All week-based patterns are unsupported since Spark 3.0, detected: Y, Please use the SQL function EXTRACT instead
```

com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All week-based patterns are unsupported since Spark 3.0, detected: Y, Please use the SQL function EXTRACT instead
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeFormatterHelper$.$anonfun$convertIncompatiblePattern$4(DateTimeFormatterHelper.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeFormatterHelper$.$anonfun$convertIncompatiblePattern$4$adapted(DateTimeFormatterHelper.scala:321)

Comment: Have a look at [date format patterns](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html), year looks to be "y". Case might matter.

Comment: Use this pattern instead `ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command worked

`select to_date(upper('01Jan1971:00:00:00'),'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss')`